# Coffeescript object is not a function error on second instantiation of class object

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescript and trying to write a class for a shopping cart feature.  When the user clicks a button, the program creates a new line item.  The following code works the first time the user clicks the button, but gives "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" the second time the button is clicked.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's the class....

```
class lineItem
 constructor: ( @item_id )->
    @menuItem = $('.menu-item[data-item-id='+@item_id+']')
    @title = @menuItem.attr('data-title')
        @item_id = @menuItem.attr('data-item-id')
    @variant_id = @menuItem.attr('data-variant-id')
    @qty = @menuItem.attr('data-qty')
    @price = @menuItem.attr('data-price')
    @total = parseFloat( @qty * @price).toFixed(2)
```

And when the button is clicked, we call this line...

```
    new lineItem( item_id)
```

EDIT:

I mis-typed.  The problem was I was doing this:

```
lineItem = new lineItem(  item_id )
```

And should have been doing this:

```
 new lineItem( item_id)
```

Comment: I don't think the error is in what you've pasted above. Only thing I see wrong with the above is that you're not checking to make sure the jquery $() call matches any elements. Maybe you have "line_item = {}" somewhere?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for looking.  The only other relevant line is  item_id = $(this).attr('data-item-id'), which is called after the button is clicked.  I've checked to make sure item_id is set correctly, and it is.  Really stuck on this one!

Comment: Thank you!  You helped me find the error on my own...could not have done it without you @Jason.

Comment: In the chrome/chromium inspector, you can have it break on uncaught exceptions, and then inspect the call tree, state of variables, etc.. Maybe then you can see what went wrong.

Comment: site note: you shouldn't stuff a constructor with logic, just initialize the instance and write separate methods for the logic.